# How to change Style.Triggers in Silverlight

Tags: xaml, silverlight

I am a beginner in SilverLight, In the below xaml code, `Style.Triggers` is not recognised by Silverlight, I've kept it commented, What is the alternate for `Style.Triggers` in this case? If it is `VisualStateManager`, How shall I change it to `VisualStateManager`?

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <!--<Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
                <Setter Property="Control.Background" Value="#d9e2ea"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                <Setter Property="Control.Background" Value="#9eceec"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>-->
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: can you please review my answer and let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need to change the background color based on a boolean value.

You can create and use a 'BooleanToBrushConverter'

### C# Code:

```
public class BooleanToBrushConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public Brush TrueBrush { get; set; }

    public Brush FalseBrush { get; set; }

    public Brush NullBrush { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Converts the data for display.
    /// </summary>
    public Object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null) return NullBrush;
        else return (bool)value ? TrueBrush : FalseBrush;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Converts the data from display
    /// </summary>
    public Object ConvertBack(Object value, Type targetType, Object parameter,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value == TrueBrush;
    }
}
```

### XAML Code:

(You will need to include this in top of your XAML)
xmlns:lc="clr-namespace:NamespaceOfYourConverterClass"

(Add below code for converter inside < Grid.Resources> < /Grid.Resources> of main < Grid>)

```
            <lc:BooleanToBrushConverter x:Key="myBooleanToColorConverter"
                                       TrueBrush="#9eceec"
                                       FalseBrush="#d9e2ea" />
```

(Now, you need to use this 'Converter' while binding Background property of your control)

Like:

```
<ItemsControl Background="{Binding IsActive, Converter={StaticResource myBooleanToColorConverter}}">
</ItemsControl>
```

Note: "IsActive" is a boolean property in ViewModel which return true(1) or false(0)